# scrapy-elasticsearch pipeline only for specific item

Tags: python, elasticsearch, scrapy, pipeline

I want to use the scrapy-elasticsearch pipeline in my scrapy project. In this project I have different items / models. These items are stored in a mysql server. In addition I want to index ONE of these items in an ElasticSearchServer.

In the documentation, however, I only find the way to index all defined items like in the code example from the settings.py below.

```
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX = 'scrapy'
ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE = 'items'
ELASTICSEARCH_UNIQ_KEY = 'url'
```

Like you can see the ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE shows that alle items have to be indexed. Is there a possibility to limit this to only one item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [current implementation](https://github.com/noplay/scrapy-elasticsearch/blob/master/scrapyelasticsearch.py) does not support sending only some items.

You could create a subclass of the original pipeline and override the `process_item` method to do what you want.

If you have the time, you could also send a pull request upstream with a proposal to allow filtering items before sending them to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I will try to create a subclass.